# Java Create a program with multiple GUI frames

Tags: java

Alright so im making a program in Java that asks the user for multiple details in continuous frames in GUI, My main question would be is there a way to put all frames in one class, and not have to create a class for each frame.

So here is what im doing:

1st frame:

Please give me your name:  [User puts name here] //Then click ok

2 frame:

Please put the first numer: [user puts first number]

Please put second number: [user puts second number]

//then click next

and so on

I cant figure out a way to do this without creating a new class for each frame.

Is there a way to put all frames in the same class. Thanks in advance

Comment: Multiple windows are annoying to the user.  Start by designing your individual UI forms around `JPanel`, these can then be added to and removed from a single `JFrame` as needed.  You could make use of a `CardLayout` to help facilitate this.  Generally speaking you want to try and keep the logic for each view as simple as possible and it sounds like you can also re-use the views to prompt for more details.  You want to control the work flow through a series of controllers and manage the data through one or more models, base on you needs

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it sounds like you do not actually need multiple frames; rather you need one frame, and its content changes. You could use several JPanels for the individual pages, and switch between them.

That said, you should *not* mash the entire dialog into a single class; rather you should practice separation of concerns, cut code into reasonable chunks, and possibly use design patterns like MVC.